# Verifying that a JavaScript object is empty using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Current Issue:**

I am looking to verify that my JavaScript Object is empty, I am trying to use the following JQuery function jQuery.isEmptyObject however, this not returning the expected results.

**Example :**

```
var searchRequest = {
    marketId: "",
    officeId: "",
    partnerId: "",
    statusId: ""
}


    if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(searchRequest)) {
        $("#searchButton").prop('disabled', true);
    }
```

Question:

How can I verify that a JavaScript Object is empty using JQuery.

Comment: The object is not empty

Comment: Dang reading the doc, feel really silly.  Thought it was doing something else when I glanced at it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[emptyObject](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/) means an object without any properties. Not an object with empty properties.

```
/**
  * @param emptyCheck Function that takes a value and returns true if it's empty to allow for flexible
  * definition of a value being empty. Defaults to a simple `!` check
  */
function areAllPropsEmpty(obj, emptyCheck) {
    emptyCheck = emptyCheck || (val)=> !val;
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (emptyCheck(obj[prop])) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you are using jQuery instead of $ (or vice versa?), there could be a conflict going on.

But you could also achieve that with native JavaScript by using:

```
Object.keys(searchRequest).length //4
```

Comment: Works fine, OP didn't understand what function meant

Comment: Yeah I missed that. But object.keys is still an alternative lol

Comment: It's an expensive alternative for the negative cases because there's no need to create the entire array.

Answer (score 0):

`searchRequest` is not an empty object. It contains key-value pairs. An empty object is `{}`.

See [the docs for $.isEmptyObject](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/).